# Why does function call from PS1 require escaping?

Tags: bash

I'm setting my prompt inside of `.bash_profile` like this

```
export PS1="\w\$(getBranchName)\n ---->"
```

My `getBranchName` function exists, and this works, fine.

My question is, why do I need to escape the call to `getBranchName` like this `\$(getBranchName)`.

In other words, why doesn't this code work, instead?

```
export PS1="\w$(getBranchName)\n ---->"
```

---

If curious, this is what the `getBranchName` function looks like

```
esc="\033"
redf="${esc}[31m"
green="${esc}[32m"
purple="${esc}[35m"
cyanf="${esc}[36m"
reset="${esc}[0m"

getBranchName() {
  if [[ "$(__git_ps1 '%s')" == "master" ]]
  then
    echo -e "${redf}$(__git_ps1)${reset}";
  else
    echo -e "${cyanf}$(__git_ps1)${reset}";
  fi
}

export PS1="\w\$(getBranchName)\n ---->"
```

Comment: Consider using `PROMPT_COMMAND` instead of trying to embed command substitutions in your prompt string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar because you want to store **this exact text** in your variable.

Try it by typing `echo "$PS1"`. You should see the exact text : `\w$(getBranchName)\n ---->`

If you didn't escape it, the function would be evaluated only once, during the allocation.

---

The bottom line is that `PS1` is a special variable : every time you display a new line in the console, the variable is evaluated to extract the display settings.

Answer (score 3):

The `PS1` variable is basically a template string (which might contain function calls) which is evaluated each time the prompt is shown.

If you want to evaluate a function each time, so that each prompt shows the result of this new execution, you need to escape the call.

If you would embed the function call directly in the string, the function would be called once immediately (i.e. likely during login) and your `PS1` will contain the result of this single function call as evaluated during your initial login. Thus, the value won't be updated again since the function is not called anymore (since the `PS1` doesn't contain the function call anymore but only the static result of one).

Answer (score 2):

It's escaped because you want it to run when the shell evaluates `$PS1` each time it's displayed, not just during the assignment.

The other expansions (which should be using `tput` unless you actually like random control codes all over your non-ANSI terminals) you want to be expanded just once, when you assign to `PS1`.